# How can you detect changes in a dynamodb table with Swift?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

As a side project, I am creating a WhatsApp messaging clone, and deployed it to AWS. In Firebase, Datastore has snapshot listeners. Is there anything like that for AWS DynamoDB?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DynamoDB stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html). Whenever an application **creates, updates, or deletes items** in the table, DynamoDB Streams writes a stream record with the primary key attributes of the items that were modified. A stream record contains information about a **data modification to a single item** in a DynamoDB table.

[image]

Once lambda receives the event you can then specify the **Action** in AWS lambda. You can look into the below example where message publishes to SNS topic once received to AWS lambda.

You can look into this example [swift/sqs_receive_message](https://www.example-code.com/swift/sqs_receive_message.asp) to get changes in swift, you can publish changes event to SQS and listen for SQS messages in swift.

> A DynamoDB stream is an ordered flow of information about changes to items in a DynamoDB table. When you enable a stream on a table, DynamoDB captures information about every modification to data items in the table.

[image]

[Streams.Lambda.Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html)